# How to do batch training using input_fn in tf.learn?

Tags: tensorflow

```
model_dir = "no_regulation"
print(model_dir)
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
      learning_rate=3,
      l1_regularization_strength=0,
      l2_regularization_strength=0),
    n_classes = n_classes,
    model_dir=model_dir)

def train_input_fn():
  print("Here!")
  return input_fn(train.sample(50000), label_column = "course_index", categorical_columns = CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS)
```

if I do the following, it batches 50000 samples for every 10 steps,

```
for i in range(40):
    for j in range(20):
        m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps = 10)
    m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn1, steps = 1, name="test1")
    m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn2, steps = 1, name="test2")
```

Is this reasonable? if I do m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps = 1), every fit call will create a checkpoint, which slows down the training a lot. Should I disable checkpoint? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

A way I found is to use `m.partial_fit` instead of `fit`. `partial_fit` does not trigger `CheckpointSaverHook`.

It seems though that `evaluate` does.